# Problems over connecting to bitbucket

Tags: networking, bitbucket, ping

Hi since yesterday I have a lot of problems connecting with bitbucket, I try to change my DNS to google (8.8.8.8) and flush the DNS cache over my pc but the connection with bitbucket is very unstable.

I think is something with my ISP, can someone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my connection is that bitbucket doesn't respond to ipv6 requests
`https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-8809?error=login_required&error_description=Login+required&state=8f5d1ab6-59f0-4256-9a53-b1f2db522062`

So I change my ipv6 configuration to work only locally and now is working ok